# What's wrong with my lein/nrepl/emacs setup?

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen, aquamacs

Newbie Clojure programmer here.  NREPL in Emacs isn't working for me.

- Aquamacs 2.5 (Emacs 23.4.1)
- nrepl.el  0.1.8
- Leiningen 2.2.0 on Java 1.6.0_51 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

My project is just the lein-generated Hello World.

Running "lein repl" in a shell works, but nrepl.el doesn't work.
Rather than winding up in the project's namespace in the repl,
I just get the default toplevel in the "user" namespace.

Should see something like:

```
my$ lein repl
nREPL server started on port 57347
REPL-y 0.2.0
Clojure 1.5.1
Hello Project
my.core=>
```

But instead see:

```
; nREPL 0.1.8-preview
user> (in-ns my.core)
CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.core, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
user>
```

In a clean nrepl.el scenario, I see two java processes going and they look plausible. One has my project on the -classpath and is implementing the actual repl (server), while the other is the client side java (-D MyProjectPath -m leiningen.core.main repl :headless).

I get the same lossage whether I get there by `m-x nrepl-jack-in` or starting in the shell and then `m-x nrepl`.  I get a repl that doesn't know my project.

I wonder if this stuff works for anyone, or if I have something installed or set up wrong?  Lots of "0.xxx" versions of things going on here...

Comment: When you do `M-x nrepl`, are you providing the port printed by `lein repl`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a quote before your namespace, try the following:

```
(in-ns 'my.core)
```

Note the ' before my.

Comment: Oh! I thought it was a macro like in CL.  Thanks! Now it looks like nrepl-jack-in is working, and my problem is reduced to why it's not starting in the project namespace in the first place and ignoring the :repl-options.

Comment: nrepl does not respect leiningen's repl-options. There is an elisp workaround here: https://github.com/kingtim/nrepl.el/issues/316

Answer (score 1):

NRepl always starts in the top-level user namespace.  Use `M-x nrepl-set-ns`, or `C-c M-n` in a Clojure buffer, to set the namespace of NRepl to the one of the buffer.

In your specific case,

- visit `src/my/core.clj`, press `C-c M-j` to start NRepl,
- switch back to the `src/my/core.clj` buffer,
- press `C-u C-c C-z` to set the NRepl namespace to `my.core` and switch back to the NRepl buffer.

`C-u C-c C-z` is a shortcut for `C-c M-n` followed by `C-c C-z` to switch to the NRepl buffer.